# How to create sort by users count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have model `lesson`. And associated model `user`. 
And i want to add sort by users count to lesson.
I thought to do something like this:

**lesson.rb**

```rb
scope :popular, -> { order("users ASC") }
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
scope :popular, -> { 
  left_outer_joins(:users).group('lessons.id').order('COUNT(users.id) DESC')
}
```

Explanation:

- `left_outer_joins` instead of just `join` to also include lessons without any users
- `group` to return each lesson only once even if there are multiple users assigned
- `count` to count the number of users per lesson (works only in combination with `group`
- the `DESC` in the count to return popular lessons (with a higher count) first

Answer (score 3):

In your `lesson` model do this

```
scope :popular, -> { left_joins(:users).group(:id).order('COUNT(users.id) DESC') }
```

I have assumed here that `lessons have_many users` and `users belongs_to lesson`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an SQL literal to group you could also make use of the arel gem.

```
scope :popular, -> {
  left_joins(:users).group(:id).order(User.arel_table[:id].count.desc)
}
```

An explanation of the above is already given by the [answer of spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476066/3982562), so I'll leave that out. You can find the arel documentation [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/9.0.0).